# gpplot2 doesn't provide continuous values with break on the X and Y axis?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My data looks like that:

```
    PCs    class             Landmarks
1     3 31.97279         All Landmarks
2     4 38.77551         All Landmarks
3     5 38.09524         All Landmarks
4     6 38.09524         All Landmarks
5     7 38.09524         All Landmarks
6     8 40.13605         All Landmarks
7     9 45.57823         All Landmarks
8    10 52.38095         All Landmarks
9    11 55.78231         All Landmarks
10   12 55.10204         All Landmarks
11   13 55.10204         All Landmarks
12   14 54.42177         All Landmarks
13   15 54.42177         All Landmarks
14   16 57.14286         All Landmarks
15   17 56.46259         All Landmarks
16   18 55.78231         All Landmarks
17   19 55.78231         All Landmarks
18   20 57.14286         All Landmarks
19   21 53.74150         All Landmarks
20   22 57.14286         All Landmarks
21   23 55.78231         All Landmarks
22   24 56.46259         All Landmarks
23   25 55.10204         All Landmarks
24   26 57.14286         All Landmarks
25   27 55.78231         All Landmarks
26   28 56.46259         All Landmarks
27   29 60.54422         All Landmarks
28   30 60.54422         All Landmarks
29   31 61.90476         All Landmarks
30   32 61.90476         All Landmarks
31   33 59.86395         All Landmarks
32   34 59.86395         All Landmarks
33   35 61.22449         All Landmarks
34   36 61.22449         All Landmarks
35   37 60.54422         All Landmarks
36   38 58.50340         All Landmarks
37   39 59.18367         All Landmarks
38   40 57.82313         All Landmarks
39   41 55.78231         All Landmarks
40   42 57.14286         All Landmarks
41   43 57.14286         All Landmarks
42   44 55.10204         All Landmarks
43   45 51.02041         All Landmarks
44   46 53.06122         All Landmarks
45   47 52.38095         All Landmarks
46   48 55.10204         All Landmarks
47   49 55.10204         All Landmarks
48   50 54.42177         All Landmarks
49   51 55.10204         All Landmarks
50   52 57.14286         All Landmarks
51   53 55.78231         All Landmarks
52   54 57.14286         All Landmarks
53   55 54.42177         All Landmarks
54   56 55.10204         All Landmarks
55   57 51.70068         All Landmarks
56   58 52.38095         All Landmarks
57   59 52.38095         All Landmarks
58   60 55.10204         All Landmarks
59    3 29.25170 Outline + no fissures
60    4 30.61224 Outline + no fissures
61    5 36.73469 Outline + no fissures
62    6 41.49660 Outline + no fissures
63    7 48.29932 Outline + no fissures
64    8 52.38095 Outline + no fissures
65    9 53.06122 Outline + no fissures
66   10 51.70068 Outline + no fissures
67   11 53.74150 Outline + no fissures
68   12 53.06122 Outline + no fissures
69   13 52.38095 Outline + no fissures
70   14 54.42177 Outline + no fissures
71   15 58.50340 Outline + no fissures
72   16 55.10204 Outline + no fissures
73   17 55.10204 Outline + no fissures
74   18 56.46259 Outline + no fissures
75   19 57.14286 Outline + no fissures
76   20 56.46259 Outline + no fissures
77   21 59.86395 Outline + no fissures
78   22 60.54422 Outline + no fissures
79   23 60.54422 Outline + no fissures
80   24 59.18367 Outline + no fissures
81   25 60.54422 Outline + no fissures
82   26 63.26531 Outline + no fissures
83   27 63.94558 Outline + no fissures
84   28 64.62585 Outline + no fissures
85   29 64.62585 Outline + no fissures
86   30 59.18367 Outline + no fissures
87   31 56.46259 Outline + no fissures
88   32 59.18367 Outline + no fissures
89   33 59.86395 Outline + no fissures
90   34 60.54422 Outline + no fissures
91   35 56.46259 Outline + no fissures
92   36 57.82313 Outline + no fissures
93   37 56.46259 Outline + no fissures
94   38 56.46259 Outline + no fissures
95   39 57.82313 Outline + no fissures
96   40 56.46259 Outline + no fissures
97   41 55.78231 Outline + no fissures
98   42 56.46259 Outline + no fissures
99   43 54.42177 Outline + no fissures
100  44 53.74150 Outline + no fissures
101  45 53.06122 Outline + no fissures
102  46 53.06122 Outline + no fissures
103  47 55.10204 Outline + no fissures
104  48 55.78231 Outline + no fissures
105  49 55.10204 Outline + no fissures
106  50 56.46259 Outline + no fissures
107  51 55.10204 Outline + no fissures
108  52 53.06122 Outline + no fissures
109  53 53.74150 Outline + no fissures
110  54 54.42177 Outline + no fissures
111  55 53.06122 Outline + no fissures
112  56 51.70068 Outline + no fissures
113  57 51.02041 Outline + no fissures
114  58 49.65986 Outline + no fissures
115  59 51.70068 Outline + no fissures
116  60 54.42177 Outline + no fissures
117   3 27.21088         Only fissures
118   4 36.05442         Only fissures
119   5 33.33333         Only fissures
120   6 34.01361         Only fissures
121   7 36.05442         Only fissures
122   8 36.73469         Only fissures
123   9 42.17687         Only fissures
124  10 42.85714         Only fissures
125  11 44.21769         Only fissures
126  12 43.53741         Only fissures
127  13 45.57823         Only fissures
128  14 46.25850         Only fissures
129  15 50.34014         Only fissures
130  16 53.74150         Only fissures
131  17 55.78231         Only fissures
132  18 55.10204         Only fissures
133  19 53.06122         Only fissures
134  20 51.70068         Only fissures
135  21 50.34014         Only fissures
136  22 51.70068         Only fissures
137  23 53.06122         Only fissures
138  24 49.65986         Only fissures
139  25 48.29932         Only fissures
140  26 48.97959         Only fissures
141  27 48.29932         Only fissures
142  28 46.25850         Only fissures
143  29 47.61905         Only fissures
144  30 47.61905         Only fissures
145  31 47.61905         Only fissures
146  32 49.65986         Only fissures
147  33 47.61905         Only fissures
148  34 48.29932         Only fissures
149  35 50.34014         Only fissures
150  36 48.29932         Only fissures
151  37 48.97959         Only fissures
152  38 47.61905         Only fissures
153  39 47.61905         Only fissures
154  40 47.61905         Only fissures
155  41 44.89796         Only fissures
156  42 43.53741         Only fissures
157  43 46.25850         Only fissures
158  44 46.25850         Only fissures
159  45 44.89796         Only fissures
160  46 47.61905         Only fissures
161  47 46.25850         Only fissures
162  48 48.29932         Only fissures
163  49 47.61905         Only fissures
164  50 46.93878         Only fissures
165  51 45.57823         Only fissures
166  52 46.25850         Only fissures
167  53 46.25850         Only fissures
168  54 46.93878         Only fissures
169  55 45.57823         Only fissures
170  56 44.89796         Only fissures
171  57 46.25850         Only fissures
172  58 47.61905         Only fissures
173  59 50.34014         Only fissures
174  60 48.97959         Only fissures
```

My ggplot2 code looks like that:

```
ggplot(df.complete.class, aes(x=PCs, y=class, group=Landmarks)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Landmarks))+
  geom_point(aes(color=Landmarks))
```

The plot looks like this

[image]

It should look something like that

[image]

Not sure what's wrong here. A long time ago I managed to plot it properly, but I have no clue how to edit the dataframe so I could plot it properly. Also, when I try to manually add breaks between the X and Y values through + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by=10), limits=c(0,100)) I get the error :

Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Please help.

Comment: Check the `class()` of the`class` :-)

Comment: Looks like you imported your data incorrectly (or your data has some bad values). Looks like class and PC weren't read in as numeric. But that would mean the error is somewhere in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: @PoGibas It's a factor. Well that's weird. Nothing makes sense with this nonsese.

Comment: Exactly, you it's not continuous data, you have to convert it to numeric

Comment: @PoGibas or rather than just converting it, figure out why it became a factor. Fix the error rather than the symptom!